# Use viewport width for spacing values but with a maximum value in Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I need to use `vw` for spacing values, but only up to a maximum screen width. In other words, as you increase the screen width I need spacing values to also increase, until you reach a certain screen width at which point the spacing values stop increasing.

I also need this screen width to be defined one place so its easy to update later.

So far I've set the max-width as a CSS variable:

```
@layer base {
  :root {
    --site-max-width: 1340px;
  }
}
```

Which I can use in a clamp function with `calc` determining the maximum value. However the CSS its a bit cumbersome:

```
padding: clamp(0px, 16vw, calc(var(--site-max-width) * 0.16))
```

And it gets even harder to write as an arbitrary value in Tailwind:

```
p-[clamp(0px,16vw,calc(var(--site-max-width)*0.16))]
```

Things can be improved a bit by moving the spacing values to the tailwind config and then using the classes like `p-c2`:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        c2: "clamp(0px,2vw,calc(var(--site-max-width)*0.02))",
        c16: "clamp(0px,16vw,calc(var(--site-max-width)*0.16))",
      },
```

But I'm hoping there's a better approach? For all its issues something like this would have been much more straightforward with CSS in JS.